# Excel is not converting all columns to PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am trying to convert Excel to PDF, but it is converting only a few columns. Please help me out of this issue.

```py
from win32com import client
  
# Open Microsoft Excel
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
  
# Read Excel File
sheets = excel.Workbooks.Open('E:\TRANSPORTER_File\Template\Primary-MarketN.xlsx')
work_sheets = sheets.Worksheets[0]
  
# Convert into PDF File
work_sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'E:\TRANSPORTER_File\Template\sds23d.pdf')
return "true"
```

Comment: Is it possible it is only showing the columns that fit on a page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your excel file but there's a possibility that printed areas were set when the file was published.

Try to set the argument 'IgnorePrintAreas' to True.

```
work_sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'E:\TRANSPORTER_File\Template\sds23d.pdf', IgnorePrintAreas = True)
```